# How to process typical set of array in shell scipt?

Tags: shell, awk

I have variable "a" which contains error I want treat this as an array and delimited with newlines.How can I convert into single line using shell script or awk?

Input Data

```
a=(BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1('$Table_Name'); END;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored)
```

expected output

```
BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1('$Table_Name'); END; | Error at line 1 | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared |ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: What you show is mostly a syntax error because of the nested parentheses.  Do you mean you have a variable with a string over multiple lines that contains the text shown?  And the output should have the lines separated by blank-pipe-blank?  The blank-pipe-blank is a nuisance; it would be relatively trivial with just pipes separating the output.  I see the sample output isn't 100% consistent; there's no space after the pipe before the second ORA-06550.  Grumble!  How's a computer supposed to deal with people who can't be consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
a="BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1('$Table_Name'); END;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"
```

You can generate one line of output using:

```
echo "$a" | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|/ | /g'
```

That yields:

```
BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1(''); END; | Error at line 1 | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PL/SQL: Statement ignored |
```

If you need the final `|` removed (it comes from the newline at the end of the `echo` output), then remove it:

```
$ echo "$a" | tr '\n' '|' | sed -e 's/|/ | /g' -e 's/ | $//'
BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1(''); END; | Error at line 1 | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PL/SQL: Statement ignored
$
```

Or don't generate it:

```
$ printf "%s" "$a" | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|/ | /g'
BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1(''); END; | Error at line 1 | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PL/SQL: Statement ignored
$
```

Of course, these outputs are very consistent and put a space around each pipe (unlike the sample output).  If there's a pipe in the data, there'll be trouble (in the form of unexpected/unwanted spaces around the pipe).

And if, perchance, you do have an array with a separate element for each line, you can adapt the code above to deal with it quite simply (using `printf`):

```
$ a=("BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1('$Table_Name'); END;"
"Error at line 1"
"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:"
"PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared"
"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:"
"PL/SQL: Statement ignored")
$ printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | tr '\n' '|' | sed -e 's/|/ | /g' -e 's/ | $//'
BEGIN DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1(''); END; | Error at line 1 | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PLS-00201: identifier 'DE_DUP_DROP_DY_TABLE1' must be declared | ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: | PL/SQL: Statement ignored
$
```